# Is there a command in arduino that can read from the keyboard to carry out a function?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm looking for a command that reads user input from the keyboard (example: user presses the letter 'a') and a function is carried out in the loop (example: if 'a' is pressed -> carry out this function).
First time posting so let me know if my etiquette is wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something like that called the serial monitor. Access it by pressing the tools menu, and then the serial monitor. I hope tthis helps!